# In typescript, how can I extend a class from it's instance?

Tags: typescript, object, oop, prototype

Hello I am trying to basically inherit the `Vehicle` class within the `Car` class without using `extends`. I am wanting to do this because I am making a browser extension and I do not have access to the class, but I do have access to the instance. This works as expected, but typescript is throwing an error on the Car class line

```
Class 'Car' incorrectly implements interface 'ICar'.
  Type 'Car' is missing the following properties from type 'ICar': steer, accelerate, brake
```

If the code works as I expect it does, it should log out "Steering" and `"Honking"`

[https://www.typescriptlang.org/playground/CarExample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```js
interface IVehicle {
    steer(): void;
    accelerate(): void;
    brake(): void;
}

interface ICar extends IVehicle {
    honk(): void;
}

class Vehicle implements IVehicle {
    constructor(){
        console.log("Vehicle created");
    }
    steer(): void {
        console.log("Steering");
    }
    accelerate(): void {
        console.log("Accelerating");
    }
    brake(): void {
        console.log("Braking");
    }
}

class Car implements ICar {
    constructor(veh: IVehicle){
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(veh));
        Object.assign(this, veh);
        // Even with the two lines above, it is saying that the object is missing the methods, "steer", "accelerate", and "brake"
    }
    honk(): void {
        console.log("Honking");
    }
}

const veh = new Vehicle();
const car = new Car(veh);

console.log(car.steer());
console.log(car.honk());
```

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `Car` interface which extends `IVehicle`

```js
interface IVehicle {
    steer(): void;
    accelerate(): void;
    brake(): void;
}

interface ICar extends IVehicle {
    honk(): void;
}

class Vehicle implements IVehicle {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Vehicle created");
    }
    steer(): void {
        console.log("Steering");
    }
    accelerate(): void {
        console.log("Accelerating");
    }
    brake(): void {
        console.log("Braking");
    }
}

interface Car extends ICar { } // <----------- SEE THIS CHANGE

class Car {
    constructor(public veh: IVehicle) {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(veh));
        Object.assign(this, veh);
        // Even with the two lines above, it is saying that the object is missing the methods, "steer", "accelerate", and "brake"
    }
    honk(): void {
        console.log("Honking");
    }
}

const veh = new Vehicle();
const car = new Car(veh);

console.log(car.steer()); // ok
console.log(car.honk()); // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL2kaw)

It is called [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: hmm I am getting `[ERR]: car.honk is not a function` but will play around with it more since it looks like the typing is gone now

Comment: `const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);` `vehProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(veh);` `setPrototypeOf(proto, vehProto);` did the trick for me, thx